# Cannot open my new react-native app in emulator

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in React-native

So i tried to start react-native.. I went to so many youtube tutorials and udemy courses..
At last i set up mu native environment.. start react-native

First i went on Getting Started React-Native site..
then i init awesomeproject to my local storage..

then run react-native run-android..
Emulator displayed correct output..

so i tried to do more projects and tried to learn react-native

so i init new project called "ChatApp" 
using

`react-native init ChatApp`

project was successfully installed.
So again i tried to

`cd ChatApp`
then
`react-native run-android`

But still i get that old "awesomeapp"
I dont no what to do
I deleted chache memory and app in the emulator and i deleted sdk in android studio after that i again try to run the command still i get that older app..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `cd ChatApp`.

Otherwise, every new project you will create with the `react-native init` command will be exactly the same! If you made some modifications but the UI doesn't update, be sure that there is no other react-native instances running.

Comment: Oh yes ```cd ChatApp```

Comment: Yes no other native instances running

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean exactly by "I get that older app"? Did you try to change some text and Refresh the app?

Comment: I meant when i am init a new project emulator will not display the new one it displays the first project that i built.. AwesomeProject is my first project so it will display all the time when i am run command  ```react-native run-android```

Comment: What I mean is "How do you know that it's displaying AwesomeProject?" as every new project created with `react-native init` are exactly identical.

Comment: emulator displays that